# Hangs on login screen

Tags: virtualbox, ram, login-screen

I'm using ubuntu in a virtual machine. My system has 3gb ram and so i assigned half to the virtual machine. It was working fine until i trained a neural network. Now i start the virtual machine and ubuntu works ok until the login screen is displayed. From there on it completely hangs or stops. Is it because of lack of RAM because I could login and do other stuff before I trained this neural network. Why would it hang at that point that I can't even type my password and it hangs!

Comment: Probably when you trained your neural network memory was fully used and ubuntu started writing what it couldn't put in memory on disk. If you saved the state of your virtual machine, it probably continues to try to handle the same operation. You could try waiting (a lot), but it may not work.

Comment: I specifically did not save my machine state. Is there a way to check if memory is full?

Comment: I allocated 35 gb to my virtual machine and this was my first neural network and I had nothing else saved. I'm using Ubuntu 64-bit on this VM